# Windows phone support for Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs

Tags: azure, windows-phone, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

does anybody from the Azure team knows at least a rough estimate of when will there be support for Windows Phone in Notifications Hub?

In any case, do you know of any alternative scalable way to send millions of notifications in a short time? using standard mobile services API calls?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone support has been added to Windows Azure. More info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/08/12/announcing-general-availability-of-windows-azure-notification-hubs-amp-support-for-sql-server-alwayson-availability-group-listeners.aspx)

Comment: Yes saw the news! :) it's awesome

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the white-bearded man with the reindeers shows up in summer. Sometimes.

Comment: oh well I'll add it to my summer wish list then :)